# How Do I Have Multiple ModelForms In Django in A SingleView?

Tags: python, django, modelform

I am trying to create A Project where  I Have A model Form Which Takes A set of data as Input.
However that is not an issue, How Do  I Have Multiple Forms of that One single Model Form .

I tried Using something like this

```
from .forms import BookForm
# Create your views here.
def home_page(request):
    context = {}
    form = BookForm(request.POST or None)
    form1 = BookForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    if form1.is_valid():
        form1.save()
    context['form']= form 
    context['form1']= form1 
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

But What Happens is the Data passed in the last form is passed in all of the forms.
How Do I Implement this in Django Handling multiple forms in single view, which gets submitted on click of a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/) in django.

Since you are using a model form, you can use something known as [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) using something known as `modelformset_factory`.

Basically formsets help you in having a list of forms. Imagine your single form now turned into a list of forms.

Checkout this [link](https://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html) for a tutorial

Let me know if you want more explanation

Comment: I Have Checked The Tutorial , I will try and implement that , much THANKS!!

Comment: let us know if you face any issues, always remember to check in SO for other answers too.
_If the answer was of help, do accept it._